# .NET Web Service - How to return an error?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, error-handling

I've been working on some web services lately in c# asp.net (3.5).

My method is like so and returns a User object consisting of some basic user-related fields (name, age, i etc)..

```
[WebMethod, SoapHeader("AuthHeader")]
public user[] Employees(int count)
{
    user[] myUsers = new user[count];

    <logic here inc. checking if user is authorised>...

    return myUsers;
}
```

If authorisation fails for the client consuming the web service id like to return an error within the web service, correctly formatted.

Whats the best practice way to achieve this? I guess simply pushing a Response.StatusCode or a Null return isnt good practice?

My current payload XML when auth'd looks like..

```
<ArrayOfUser>
    <user>
        <empid>57344</empid>
        <firstname>Dave</firstname>
        <surname>Johnson</surname>
    </user>
    <user>
        <empid>17324</empid>
        <firstname>Mike</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
    </user>
</ArrayOfUser>
```

If an error occurs should I be returning something like...?

```
    <soap:error>
        <errorcode>12345</errorcode>
        <errorstring>Invalid username/password</errorstring>
    </soap:error>
```

Or is there a better best practice way?

Second issue is, how would I structure my method so I could return such a XML structure? At present my "Employees" method is of type "User[]" so must return an array of type "User", but if theres been an error I want to return a different type to simulate an XML structure as above or even a simple string stating an error has occured.

How would I achieve this?

Any help would be great! Cheers!

Comment: You should return a different `MessageType` instead of user from the web service and that message type should be populated based on the outcome of your method, e.g return MessageType should be `ServiceResult` with property `users[]` , `status[success/failure]` and `StatusMessage[any message]`

Comment: You could throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Just have your method throw an exception - the .Net framework will convert that into a SOAP error message.

If you want more control over the SOAP error message returned then throw a [`SoapException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

**For error handling :** You need a good exception handling framework to support your application.  If you are using enterpriselibrary exception handling use the below line of code.

```
enter code here

catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Client Service Policy");
}
```

It again depends on what message you want to show it to the user.  You can log the actual error message and throw customized message to the end user, you can do with the exception handling framework.

You can get more details on implementing exception handling framework.
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31463/1954

**For returning xml :** you can create the elements as shown below.  Finally you can convert the xelement to string and you can use the string in your caller method (the string is nothing but XML)

```
enter code here

string[] directoriesList = Directory.GetDirectories(System.IO.Path.GetFullPat ("\\mynetworkpath")));
XElement foldersXML = new XElement("Folders");
foldersXML.Add(from directory in valueList select new XElement("Folders", new XAttribute("name", directory.Split('\\')[directory.Split('\\').Length - 1])));
```